# Legacy table with column named "class" in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a legacy table that my rails application shares with another application. It has a column called "class". The first time I reference any attribute in that model, I get an error.  Subsequent references to attributes work.  Is there a good workaround for this, or should I just go modify the other application that uses this table (ugh)?

```
>> Member::Ssg.find(:first)
 => #<Member::Ssg ssg_key: #<BigDecimal:10b169688,'0.253E3',4(8)>, org_id: 2, academic_year: 2006, class: true, next_due_date: "2011-06-01", submitted_date: "2006-02-13", notes: nil, owner_id: "1">
 >> Member::Ssg.find(:first).notes
 NoMethodError: undefined method `generated_methods' for true:TrueClass
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:247:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):2
>> Member::Ssg.find(:first).notes
=> nil
```

SOLUTION:
I went with a combination of the Bellmyer solution and adding the code below to my model

```
 class << self
   def instance_method_already_implemented?(method_name)
     return true if method_name == 'class'
     super
   end
 end
```

Comment: Just want to say that your updated solution worked great.  Thank you!

Comment: @JustinHoldsclaw, did you try it on Rails 4 or 5?

Comment: @MahmoudM.Abdel-Fattah this was on Rails 4.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**NOTE:** Please see the updated solution at the end of this answer.  Leaving the original outdated solution for historic reasons.

This has come up often enough (legacy column names interfering with ruby/rails) that I might just make a plugin out of this.  Here's how you can fix it right away, though.  Create this file in your app:

```
# lib/bellmyer/create_alias.rb
module Bellmyer
  module CreateAlias
    def self.included(base)
      base.extend CreateAliasMethods
    end

    module CreateAliasMethods
      def create_alias old_name, new_name
        define_method new_name.to_s do
          self.read_attribute old_name.to_s
        end

        define_method new_name.to_s + "=" do |value|
          self.write_attribute old_name.to_s, value
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And now, in your model:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Bellmyer::CreateAlias
  create_alias 'class', 'class_name'
end
```

The first parameter to create_alias is the old method name, and the second parameter is the new name you want to call it, that won't interfere with rails.  It basically uses the `read_attribute` and `write_attribute` methods to interact with the column instead of the ruby methods that get defined by ActiveRecord.  Just be sure to use the new name for the field everywhere, like so:

```
member.class_name = 'helper'
```

This works with ruby 1.8, but I haven't tested with ruby 1.9 yet.  I hope this helps!

**UPDATE:** I've found a better solution that works in Rails 3, the safe_attributes gem. I've written a blog post explaining how to use it, with example code snippets, and a full sample app you can download from github and play around with.  Here's the link:

[Legacy Database Column Names in Rails 3](http://kconrails.com/2011/01/28/legacy-database-table-column-names-in-ruby-on-rails-3/)

Comment: This doesn't quite do the trick.  It allows me to reference the value of the class column, but I still go the error NoMethodError: undefined method `generated_methods' for true:TrueClass
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:247:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):2

Answer (score 0):

The following works in Rails 6.0.2.2

```
class ReasonCode < ApplicationRecord    
  class << self
    def instance_method_already_implemented?(method_name)
      return true if method_name == 'class'
      super
    end
  end

  def as_json(options={})
    add_class = attributes.keys.include?('class')
    if add_class
      if options[:only]
        add_class = Array(options[:only]).map(&:to_s).include?('class')
      elsif Array(options[:except])
        add_class = Array(options[:except]).map(&:to_s).exclude?('class')
      end
    end

    options[:except] = Array(options[:except])
    options[:except].push('class')
    json = super(options)

    json['class'] = attributes['class'] if add_class

    json
  end
end
```

Adapted from this answer https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/activerecord-column-with-reserved-name-class/125705/2. The as_json method was added because rendering the record as json gave a SystemStackError (stack level too deep). I followed the [serialization code in the Rails repo](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2a12fe0b122e37e3321d4a53af013a2eb596ccd1/activemodel/lib/active_model/serialization.rb#L130-L134) to only render the class attribute if specified in the as_json options.